# Echarts dataZoom slider handleIcon shape not working

Tags: echarts

In the echarts docs at https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataZoom-slider.handleIcon the handle icon for data zoom slider has shape options like "circle", "rectangle" etc.

However these shapes doesn't seem to work.
If we specify `dataZoom: [{ handleIcon: "circle" }]` the handle icon just disappears.

Is the implementation for this API still pending or else?

Answer (score 1):

You misinterpreted the documentation. The method `handleIcon` expects a string of path but not some shape identifier. Please take a look at the [tests](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/search?l=HTML&q=handleIcon) where you can found how to use this method.

However, you can define the icons outside of the chart configuration and use inside with identifier:

```js
var icons = {
  circle: 'M17.498,11.697c...',
  square: 'M17.498,11.697c...'
}

var option = {
  //...
  dataZoom: [{ handleIcon: icons['circle'] }]
}
```

Comment: okay, why would they give shape options in a drop-down in the docs under "Try It"

Comment: Maybe for future versions, maybe it's a bug ... I don't know, I've never used it the way you want and in the docs this is not described. Trying to report as bug?